# React web app: 'Hide' elements of a table so those with value of zero are not shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have created an educational app to list products for an online store. I have created a table for these products, but I would like to hide those whose quantity have run out (i.e., hide the whole row when `quantity=0`).

I create the table from arrays in the state using `array.map`:

```
<table className="center-table" style={{border:'solid',}}>
      <thead className="has-text-black-bis" style={{backgroundColor:"#e6be8a"}}>
        <tr>
          <th >Product Name:</th>
          <th >Unit Price:</th>
          <th >Quantity Available:</th>
          <th >Buy!</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className="has-text-black-bis">
        {this.state.indices.map((a) => (
          <tr className="rows">
            <td ><strong>{this.state.itemNames[a]}</strong></td>
            <td ><strong>{this.state.costs[a]} Wei</strong></td>
            <td ><strong>{this.state.quantities[a]}</strong></td>
            <td >
              Qty: <input type="text" className='table-input' name="inputs" value={this.state.inputs[a]} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
              <button type="button" className='buy-btn' onClick={()=>this.buyItem(a)}> Buy!</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would imagine a for loop would work well, but I have not been able to implement this within JSX.

Comment: mention the whole component with states initialisation...for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a filter before the map method:

```
this.state.indices.filter((a) => a.quantity !== 0).map((a) => (...
```

You can also just go

```
this.state.indices.filter((a) => a.quantity).map((a) => (...
```

Because 0 is considered falsy in JS.

Comment: I believe for this 'indices' would need to be an object containing all the quantities? Right now, each value is a separate array in state and I use indices to map through them- I had trouble storing them in an object but I will try that again.

Comment: {this.state.indices.filter((a) => this.state.quantities[a] !== 0).map((a) => (... this is how I think this would translate to my current set-up but I imagine since quantities is a separate array this isn't working.

Comment: I'm not sure how the object is structured, but yes you're getting the idea.